# How to set custom add-in's pinned by default when user opens outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to set my outlook add-in pinned by default when user opens outlook. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the very first time user has to pin your add-in. Once pinned, your add-in will be automatically opened every time user opens Outlook.

There is no way for the add-in to pin by default without user interaction in Outlook.
If you believe this is a good feature to have, you can add the idea in https://outlook.uservoice.com